# How to manage normal html form submission in symfony?

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony

I'm new to symfony and according to my knowledge symfony provide its own functions for creating forms i.e.

```
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
            ->add('task', TextType::class)
            ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Task'))
            ->getForm();
```

but I don't want to create form using symfony. I have my own html form so can i integrate it with symfony and how to manage html form submission and its action using symfony? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to build the form by yourself? And after all, what keeps you from building the form and not output it? You won't be able to handle a form submission through Symfony without building the form through Symfony

Comment: It is possible dude.Please refer the below answer and for more please refer https://www.sitepoint.com/building-processing-forms-in-symfony-2/

Comment: Well, that depends: the answer given does not relate to handling of a form submission (which can integrate validation and direct handling of models), but to a very basic handling of data coming in from a request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's way easier to manage forms, their validation and handling if you use Symfony Forms, however, you can still use normal plain HTML form in twig templates and in the Controller by using Request object get form data from there by using:

```
$request->request->get('formElementName');
```

Symfony doesn't enforce using the Symfony forms, but instead, I highly suggest using them anyway.

Comment: hello @janmyszkier can you please give me detail code how to provide path in action and how to manage controller code.so it would be easy for me to understand.

Comment: path to action should be the same as Route path, see http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html for what routes are and how paths work, the question you're asking is another issue, so either contact me directly (skype: janmyszkier. I'll be happy to help ) or add another stackoverflow question.

Comment: 'It's way easier to manage forms, their validation and handling if you use Symfony Forms'

If and only if you do not want to do anything beyond basic forms. Anything remotely complex becomes a nightmare fuelled hellscape from which there is no return.

Comment: @NeilMasters For what it is worth, I gave up using Symfony forms years ago.  They kept sending me to a nightmare fueled hellscape from which I was fortunate to return.  Symfony forms are fine for trivial cases but quickly break down when doing something beyond CRUD.